# Javascript TypeError: this.init is not a function Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

This is my Javascript code

```
    Html5Template_300x250 = function(config) {
       this.config = config;
        var self = this;
        this.init();       
        Html5Template_300x250.prototype = {
            // Function That Creates Element Var
            d: function(id) {
                return document.getElementById(id);
            },

            // Initialize DCO HTML5 template
            init: function() {
                alert("test1");
                this.startAd();

            },

            startAd: function() {
                alert("test2");

            }

        };
    }
```

From the HTML file i am creating method like this

```
 var sr_Config = {            
            bgColor:'#fff',
            ctaText:'Learn More',
            border: 'true'
        };


        var Html5Template = new Html5Template_300x250(sr_Config);
```

But i am getting Error

> TypeError: this.init is not a function this.init();

I am not sure what is wrong here i have also tried self.init() but still it is not working.

I am new to javascript and learning OOPS in Javascript if anyone can tell me what i am doing wrong here that would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: you should define the init method before you use/call it. (so write the call to init below the init function itselfs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assing the methods to the prototypes properties (at least thats how i do it). You also need to do so before you call the function (above).

```
Html5Template_300x250 = function(config) {
    this.config = config;
    var self = this;

    Html5Template_300x250.prototype.d = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    };

    Html5Template_300x250.prototype.startAd = function() {
        alert("test2");
    };

    // Initialize DCO HTML5 template
    Html5Template_300x250.prototype.init = function() {
        alert("test1");
        this.startAd();
    };

    self.init();
}
```

Another way to do this w/o the `prototype`-stuff would be sth. like that:

```
Html5Template_300x250 = function(config) {
    this.config = config;
    var self = this;

    this.d = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    };

    // and so on..

    self.d('myid');
}
```

See this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btLbbbkn/) with some sample code.

Further interesting reading on the topic OOP in JS is provided by JS-Guru [Douglas Crocford](http://javascript.crockford.com/javascript.html) ;)

Comment: thanks but i am confused how can i fix my current code? what i have to add can you explain a bit thanks

Comment: see the updated answer. maybe you need to make some adjustments, but thats how it works basically...

Comment: i've also added a much easier way (imo). if youre interested in the topic, see the link i provided in the answer.